# Python default "sorted" use Merge or Quick sort? What algorithm used?

Tags: python-3.x

Python default sort algorithm is Merge sort or Quick sort?

For example, below sorting students by age.

```
        >>> student_tuples = [
        ...     ('john', 'A', 15),
        ...     ('jane', 'B', 12),
        ...     ('dave', 'B', 10),
        ... ]
        >>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
        [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python actually uses something called `timsort`. You can learn more about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/timsort-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-youve-never-heard-of-36b28417f399)

Comment: Great thanks. But how do I know underneath "sorted" it's actually Timesort algorithm? Although from the link it reads: "Timsort is a sorting algorithm that is efficient for real-world data and not created in an academic laboratory. Tim Peters created Timsort for the Python programming language in 2001."

Comment: You can read their documentation from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) or you can check out the actual code for it from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c)

Comment: The doc and the comments in the code do not state it's Timesort. I guess you read the code, this is how you knew it's Treesort?